# Compare a Factor and String in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I keep running into this issue, I have a dataset such as:

```
'data.frame':   5362 obs. of  5 variables:
  $ productname: Factor w/ 160 levels "Accent Mugs",..: 
  $ othervar: something else
```

I want to filter by what `productname` is:

```
out_ds <- data %>% 
  filter(isTRUE(all.equal(productname, "Woven Blankets")))
```

That doesn't work. How do I test equality between a factor label and a string value?

Comment: Have you tried `filter(productname == "Woven Blankets")` ?

Comment: A bit of a kludge, but what about id = which(as.character(productname0 == "Woven Blankets") ; df = df[id,]

Comment: works with `iris` dataset , `iris %>% filter(Species == "versicolor")`

Comment: Using `all.equal` will be tough in this case because `all.equal` also tests the number of factor levels between the variable and the text you supply. You would then have to use `apply` (most likely) to test the condition row wise (not tested). It would be better to use `==` or `%in%` to test the conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `all.equal` in your `filter` statement is comparing a `factor` `productname` to the `string` `"Woven Blankets"` so it will not return `TRUE` but it will return a description of the the differences between the two arguments, see the [R documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/all.equal.html) for `all.equal`.

Using the `iris` dataset, you can see this when you run:

```
all.equal(iris$Species, "versicolor")

> "'current' is not a factor"
```

@AntoniosK suggestion in the comment should work for your `data.frame` as the `filter` function in the `dplyr` package works easily with `factor` objects.

```
out_ds <- data %>% 
    filter(productname == "Woven Blankets")
```